# Unable to login to azure vm

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I created an azure vm, then logged in to it. Later when I try to login using the same password, it gives invalid credentials error. Also, when I try to reset the password. It fails. Could anyone tell me a solution for the same?

Comment: Not sure how anyone will be able to help here - maybe contact support? This isn't programming-related.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, maybe we can try to add a new user to solve this problem.

> azure vm reset-access -g stlvm -n stl-centos7 -u test -p
>   examplePassword

If your VM is running, maybe we can analyze the sshd logs by using CustomScriptForLinux.

You may refer to the following links for how to use CustomScriptForLinux:

https://serverfault.com/questions/810363/configuring-fixing-ssh-access-on-a-centos-7-2-box-in-azure

Regards,

Walter